# Angular: conditionally set 'credentials' option in fetch

Tags: angular, fetch

For an Angular app I need to make a few API calls to a Laravel backend, which has to temporarily store some data in a PHP session. The Angular app is running on `http://localhost:4200`, while the Laravel backend is running on a local `.test` domain. In order to ge the Laravel session cookie to work cross-domain, I have to set the `credentials` option to `include` locally. This won't be needed in production though as they'll both be running on the same domain.

To solve this I want to use a setting in my environment files (I've got one locally and one for production). However, when I simply add `credentials: environment.credentials` (`credentials` in `environment` is set to `include` locally, `same-origin` for production) to the `fetch` call, I get the error `Types of property 'credentials' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RequestCredentials'`, which makes sense. To fix this I could change it to `credentials: environment.credentials === 'include' ? 'include' : 'same-origin'` (which works), but that seems like an unnecessary extra check, is there a better/simpler way to dynamically set this value, or is it possible to cast a `string` to `RequestCredentials`?

For reference, my fetch call looks like this atm:

```
const url = environment.apiUrl + '/slug/';
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: environment.credentials === 'include' ? 'include' : 'same-origin',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: ...
});
```

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21618

Comment: If my answer satisfied you, please consider accepting it, otherwise, could you detail why it doesn't work?

Comment: Was having some connectivity issues so couldn't try out whether or not it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`environment.credentials` is a string, while credentials is a `RequestCredentials`. You can however convert string into `RequestCredentials` like this:

```
const url = environment.apiUrl + '/slug/';
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: environment.credentials as RequestCredentials,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: ...
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for when I meant casting, thanks!